# Vim keymapping for moving as many characters as the value contained in `textwidth` internal variable

Tags: vim

Vim features an internal variable `textwidth`, which determines how many characters will be printed on screen before adding an `<EOL>` character to wrap the text to a next line.

I would like to create a mapping, let's say `<c-j>`, for which I would like the cursor to move a number of characters to the *right* equal to the value stored in `textwidth`. This would simulate "going down a line" when the text is wrapped.

I assume that a simple approach would be along the lines of:

```
nnoremap <c-j> {textwidth}l
```

However, I have not found a way of evaluating the value of `textwidth` so that it cant be used as a `count` for the command `l`.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: Isn't what the command `gj` is for ? It will go down by one line visually on a long line with text wrapped.

Comment: With the `l` command, that's characters to the _right_, not _left_ as you've written.

Comment: You are both right! I've edited the question to reflect that i want movement to the *right*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways: One is the interpolation of `&textwidth` (the `&` sigil turns the option name into a variable that contains its value; cp. [`:help :let-option`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#%3Alet-option)), as in @RuslanOsmanov's answer:

```
nnoremap <silent> <C-j> :execute "normal!" &textwidth . 'l'<CR>
```

Another is [`:help :map-expression`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Amap-expression), which automatically evaluates the mapping's right-hand side as a Vimscript expression. I would prefer this one, as it's shorter:

```
nnoremap <expr> <C-j> &textwidth . 'l'
```

#### Further improvements

You probably should consider what to do if `'textwidth'` is unset, i.e. zero. Unhandled, this would result in a `0l` motion, i.e. going to the second character in the line. You can use a conditional to turn this into a no-op, for example. (Or make it beep by returning `'<Esc>'` instead of '').

```
nnoremap <expr> <C-j> (&textwidth == 0 ? '<Esc>' : &textwidth . 'l')
```

#### Really needed?

Vim has a [`:help gj`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#gj) command (and variants for the other directions) built-in, that does something similar to what you're trying to implement. Unless you're attempting to solve a special case (e.g. disregarding options like `'showbreak'` that further reduce the amount of characters actually shown), it would be advisable to just use (and maybe remap) the built-ins.

Comment: You're right about the off-by-one character and your solution with using `.` works perfectly! Well done.

Comment: This is such a great answer. Thank you very much for the super helpful insight. Turns out that I can just use, as you mentioned, `gj`.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to an option value by prefixing its name with an ampersand, e.g. `&textwidth`.

Moving `&textwidth` characters to the right can be run as follows:

```
:execute "normal!" &textwidth 'l'
```

where the arguments (`"normal!"`, `&textwidth`, and `'l'`) are concatenated with a space and executed as an Ex command.

So your mapping might look something like this:

```
:nnoremap <silent> <c-j> :execute "normal!" &textwidth 'l'<cr>
```

Comment: Nice answer, I tried it and it works greatly. Just that in my case I had to substract one: `&textwidth-1`. I mean: `:se &textwidth?` gives me `78` and on a very long line `78l` gives me the same result as `:execute "normal!" &textwidth-1 'l'`

Comment: @Yoric: The problem is the space between the number and `l`. Vim treats that as the `<space>` command, which luckily does the same as `l`, but that's creating the off-by-one. Direct concatenation (with `.`) fixes the problem.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I have chosen the other answer as the valid one because it goes the extra step to talk about conditionals and the `gj` command. But your answer still solves my issue! Thanks again